# Global variable not update on snap Firebase Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase

// Global variable
var userData = {};

```
@override void initState() {super.initState();getData();}
```

```
getData() async {var userSnap = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Usuario').doc(widget.user.uid).get();
```

```
userData = userSnap.data()!;
print(userData['fazendaNome']); // here is ok
setState(() {});
```

}

// when I try`your text` access the value above doesn't work (return null)
Text(userData['somefield']

I'm try to get some value of collection.